# Why does this table ignore the row / column dimensions I'm specifying?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
<table class="resizer">
    <tr>
        <td class="handle"></td>
        <td class="handle topedge"></td>
        <td class="handle"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="handle leftedge"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="handle rightedge"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="handle"></td>
        <td class="handle bottomedge"></td>
        <td class="handle"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS for the table looks like this:

```
.resizer {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
}

.resizer .handle {
    background-color: #500;
}

.resizer .topedge {
    height: 2px;
    cursor: n-resize;
}

.resizer .leftedge {
    width: 2px;
    cursor: w-resize;
}

.resizer .rightedge {
    width: 2px;
    cursor: e-resize;
}

.resizer .bottomedge {
    height: 2px;
    cursor: s-resize;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not paying any attention to my size specifications. What I want is:

- The top and bottom row to have a height of `2px`
- The left and right column to have a width of `2px`

Something like this (the numbers represent the cell number):

```
1122222222222222222233
44                  66
44                  66
44                  66
7788888888888888888899
```

### Code

You can see a live demo and make corrections to the HTML / CSS here:

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/george_edison/9SmQg/8/

Comment: Wouldn't you be better of using `<div>`s instead of `<td>`s?

Comment: @Kevin: But then how would cells 2, 5, and 8 keep their widths equal?

Comment: @Georige: http://jsfiddle.net/3GyAK/1/ (Only tested in Chrome, probably needs some more fooling around).

Comment: @Kevin: That's pretty clever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

> http://jsfiddle.net/T9TpL/

Comment: **Wow.** All it needed was an empty space?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I typed this sentence a few times this weekend :)

Tables are dealt with differently by browsers, the recs/specs are (deliberately?) lenient, they get to do what they want .. tables are designed to stretch - you cannot fix their dimensions any more - at least not reliably cross-browser

one way you would do this is using absolute positioning.. your table is already absolutely positioned the rest would be a breeze when positioned inside an absolutely positioned div

recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474951/css-make-divs-inherit-a-height/5480017#5480017) and example [**here**](http://jsbin.com/oqozo5)

**no widths required**

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9SmQg/9/

Comment: I'd prefer not to specify an explicit width though.

Comment: @George Yeah I suspected that.