# Make CSS Div height Equal To Contents without changing width

Tags: html, css

I would like for the Div element's height to only expand to as wide as my table element becomes, but keep it's width as long as the screen size. using 'display: inline-block' will wrap both width and heights. for example the following code will fit also width.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; float: right; background-color: green;">
  <div style="float: right;">first item</div>
  <div style="float: left;">second item</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: Please create a code case for it (with the problem you are having) and paste that code into this question.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer I added a code case.

Comment: Good start. Now, which ones are you considering your table element? Is it the first `<div>` or do you have a table that wraps the added code? If the later, please add the table to the code aswell.

Comment: Here is a good explanation on why this can't be done directly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474951/css-make-divs-inherit-a-height

Comment: I think I found the solution. I added 'width=100%' after 'display: inline-block;'
thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ali So *that* was what you wanted. Then I can simplify it for you. Remove `display: inline-block`, `float: right` and the newly added `width:100%`. If the `<div>` is a block (like it is from the start) it will expand to the maximum width inside its container and if it uses up all of the width, no float is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try;

```
.container div{
    width:50%;
    background: green
}
```

with

```
<div class="container" style="background: green;width:100%">
  <div style="float: right">first item</div>
  <div style="float: left">second item</div>
</div>
```

***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/EWuwn/)*** is a live demo. You may also try adding separate classes for left and right divs or may use CSS3 `:nth-child()` Selector