# CSS - div height

Tags: html, css

I am getting a little gap between child-div and its parent-div. Is it possible for child-div to on its parent-div height? or (the way around)possible if the parent-div can scope the height of its child-div for not to overlap or get some extra spaces.

I have a DOM like this:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="parent-image">
  </div>

 <div class="child-div">
 </div>

</div>
```

here is my CSS:

```
.parent-image:{
  height:60px;
}
.parent-div{
    border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.child-div{
      ????
}
```

Comment: This post might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474951/css-make-divs-inherit-a-height

Comment: Make up a fiddle or online example that hows this in action, as your code doesn't demonstrate the issue.

Comment: recreate the problem on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZMygK/ seems just fine to me...

Comment: I think the OP wants to try and inherit height without specifying it on the parent.  Which I do not believe is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify `height: 100%;` it will take the height of the parent.

If your child has padding, you need to change its box-sizing.

```
.child {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If your child has more content than the parent, you either need to tell it to scroll, or hide.  Note that on some browsers the scroll-bar will be inside the div, and on other browsers, it'll be on the outside.

```
.parent.c .child {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or

```
.parent.d .child {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [Demo of All](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/LkzgD)

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, you can set your child-div to:

```
.child-div{
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Xq7zQ/

Comment: I believe a height has to be specified on the parent (`.parent-div`) for this to work.  I belive the OP wants to inherit the parents height based on the content the parent contains.  Or something like that.